# What Happens To Auto Increment, If we delete a row in SQL

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

this is a beginner question. As i dont have access to Microsoft SQL Server right now. My Question is regarding the Auto Increment Feature.

> http://s10.postimg.org/lev8tvu7t/image.jpg
>
> Just take a look at the above table. Assume that the id field has
>   given an Auto Increment option in Microsoft SQL Server. What happens
>   if i delete the third row ?? I mean what happens to the numbering ?
>   Will the ID 103 will be automatically changed to 102 ?? or it will
>   stay the same, ommiting the '102' number ?

Also i have another question too...

> http://s30.postimg.org/7exbjw7r5/image.jpg
>
> In the above table, just assume that i have truncated all the fields.
>   After that i inserted another set of values. What will happens to the
>   ID (Auto Increment ON) field. What will be the ID of newly entered
>   details ?? Will it be 105, 106 and so on or it will start again from 1
>   ?? (In the example shown the ID starts from 100, just think it starts
>   from 1).
>
> I also want to know what happens on both conditions.(ie, 1. on
>   truncating table and 2. deleting all table details).

Comment: In mysql it carries on where you left off, there a command to reset it though: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Comment: You can run tests on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Can you define "truncated all the fields"?

Comment: Adam, I want to know on bothe the conditions. for both the example images provided. Hope you will take a look and provide an explanation.

Comment: Yeah What happens if i do TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_NAME; and i re-enter another set of table details?? Also what happens if i do DELETE FROM table_name WHERE <ALL COLUMNS>; and i re-enter another set of table details??

In both the above conditions what happens to auto increment ? When i enter new details will the numbering starts again from where i left of, ie 105, 106 and so on (or) will it again starts from 1,2,3 etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rows you already inserted will remain the same. You could try it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.floob(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), name NVARCHAR(32));

INSERT dbo.floob(name) VALUES(N'bob'),(N'frank'),(N'KRIZTE');

DELETE dbo.floob WHERE id = 2;

SELECT id, name FROM dbo.floob;
```

Results:

```
id   name
--   ------
1    bob
3    KRIZTE
```

Now, second question, not quite sure what you mean by "truncated all the fields" - if you `DELETE` from the table, the `IDENTITY` sequence is maintained. e.g.:

```
DELETE dbo.floob;

INSERT dbo.floob(name) SELECT N'aaron';

SELECT id, name FROM dbo.floob;
```

Results:

```
id    name
--    -----
4     aaron
```

However, if you issue `TRUNCATE TABLE`, the `IDENTITY` sequence is reset.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.floob;

INSERT dbo.floob(name) SELECT N'bert';

SELECT id, name FROM dbo.floob;
```

Results:

```
id    name
--    ----
1     bert
```

For further info, please see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+identity+columns+work+sql+server).

Comment: What i want to know is. if i do TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_NAME; and i re-enter another set of table details?? Also what happens if i do DELETE FROM table_name WHERE <ALL COLUMNS>; and i re-enter another set of table details?? In both the above conditions what happens to auto increment ? When i enter new details will the numbering starts again from where i left of, ie 105, 106 and so on (or) will it again starts from 1,2,3 etc. - And you understand it correctly. That was a clean explanation. You cleared my doubt..!!